# what should be the version for com.google.android.gms:play-services: x.x.x for minsdk version 7?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I developed a small puzzle app. what should be the version for com.google.android.gms:play-services: x.x.x for minsdk version 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None. Google Play Services requires Gingerbread (API9) or newer:

> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use
>   either:
>
> A compatible Android device **that runs Android 2.3 or higher** and
>   includes Google Play Store. The Android emulator with an AVD that runs
>   the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

PS: why you need to support API7? [Noone uses it](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can see 8.4.0 here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup at the moment I write the answer. I don't know how often they update it, but usually it's updated. You don't necessary need the newest version though.